# Regex not working in one circumstance

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, function

This code is an excerpt from a larger project, but I have tried to pull out the relevant material and provide that only.

I have a project, and the part that I need help with is this:
Product codes are generated by users via a series of drop-downs and radio buttons. The one part that will always stay the same is that there is a

```
(x11)
```

at the end of each line with a product number, where 11 represents the quantity of the product code, and will also change.

A demo of the relevant code is available at [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hL2ajpqm/).

My problem is this: the deleteItem() function works when the code is displayed as

```
ca-fefefsefef (x45)
```

but not when I tried to change the format to display the quantity as

```
ca-fjeoisfne Qty. 78
```

(The difference being in the way the quantity is displayed, not the code itself)

## All of the product codes are examples, are not real, and the actual codes will vary in length and content. The quantity of each product code will change as well.

I suppose what I am asking for is a new regex to replace the old one in the deleteitem() function, but this regex needs to work with

```
Qty. 23
```

where 23 is the quantity, and will change from code to code.

Basically, the selection of code that I have provided at the fiddle is designed to display each product code and its corresponding quantity in a drop down. The codes are stored in an array, as well as the quantities(in a separate array). The purpose of the deleteitem() function is when the delete button is clicked next to a product code and quantity, it not only deletes the product code and quantity from the drop-down, but it also deletes the corresponding items in the product_codes and quantities arrays. (with the help of the removetextfromarray() function)

Make sure to watch the web console, it will display the arrays before and after the items are deleted. You'll note that when the quantity is displayed as (x99), it works, but if you change it to Qty. 99, it removes the items from the dropdown, but does not remove the corresponding items from their arrays.

So what I need is a new regex to replace the old one (or possibly a new/updated deleteitem() function that will work with the quantity display format as

```
Qty. 3
```

instead of

```
(x3)
```

and will delete  both the items both from the drop down, and delete the two items from their corresponding arrays.

Please keep in mind the following: The product codes in the array, and the quantities in their own array will change, the ones I have provided are examples. There may be more than three, and they will change in length. I am also unable to use Jquery.

If you can spare the time, I would love any help you can give. I've spent literally hours trying to build new regexes that will work, trying to uncode the existing one (I didn't write it) and such. A working fiddle would be absolutely GREAT. Thanks so much for any help.

If I'm not being clear, please comment and I'll be happy to answer any questions about it or make updates. Thanks again!

Comment: Code should be posted here as part of the question. It's OK to link a jsfiddle, but duplicate the code here.

Comment: @Pointy I would've but i wasn't sure whether it would excede the max length limit for in-post code, and JSFIddle has no such limitations. Next Time I will. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this: `/\w*Qty\. \d+$/`

(see example here https://jsfiddle.net/xes3eLxp/1/)

That means, match:

- Zero or more white space characters (`\w*`),
- `Qty.` (`Qty\.`),
- A single space (),
- One or more digits (`\d+`),
- The end of the line (`$`).

Consider the sample string: "ckj-fjeieofj Qty. 56"

The above regex would match `Qty. 56`

```js
product_codes = ['cr-rttrnhuj3', 'ckj-fjeieofj', 'jjff-cr-sd'];
quantities = ['2', '56', '98'];
myfunction = function () {
    document.getElementById('cart_body').innerHTML = '';
    cart_text = '';
    emp = '<div class="close_button" onclick="deleteItem(this)">x</div>';
    open_span = '<span class="close_span">';
    close_span = '</span>';
    elf = '<br class="none"/>';
    for (i = 0; i < product_codes.length; i++) {
        cart_text += "<div>" + open_span + product_codes[i] + "   Qty. " + quantities[i] + close_span + emp + elf + "</div>";
    }
    document.getElementById('cart_body').innerHTML = cart_text;

}
function removeTextFromArray(array, text){

  for (var i=array.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
   if (array[i] === text) {
    array.splice(i, 1);
    quantities.splice(i, 1);
    return array;
   }
  }
 }
myfunction();
hider2 = function () {
    cart_bod = document.getElementById('cart_body');
    cart_bod.classList.toggle('closed');
}
//below function is the important one
deleteItem = function (item) {
    //dot instead of hashtag
    item.parentElement.remove();
    console.log('set');
    var textInNode = item.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("close_span")[0].innerHTML;
    textInNode = textInNode.replace(/\w*Qty\. \d+$/g, "").trim();
    //new regex is  /*\Qty[^)]*\ */g
    //old is / *\([^)]*\) */g
    codes = removeTextFromArray(product_codes, textInNode);
    console.log(product_codes)
    console.log(quantities);
}
```

```css
body {
    font: 12px tahoma;
}
.centered {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#debug-box {
}
#configurator-container {
}
#submit-box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#unit-container {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    width: 50%;
    /*change this width to test whether it'll fit in the SEI website'*/
}
#quantity {
    width: 40px;
}
.select-label {
}
dt {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    text-align: right;
    cursor: default;
}
br {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.none {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.s_container {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.sm_it {
    font-style: italic;
}
i {
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
input[type='email'] {
    width: 235px;
}
.second_line_italics {
    padding-left: 40px;
}
#configurator-container {
    background-image: url("data:image/gif;base64,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");
}
select {
    width: 235px;
}
input[type='number'] {
    width: 235px;
}
.twin_btns {
    display: inline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.twin_divs {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    z-index: 300;
    position relative;
    text-align: center;
}
#second_line_ex-length {
    width: 215px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#b-length-1 {
    width: 145px;
}
#b-length-2 {
    width: 145px;
}
.hidden {
    color: grey;
    pointer-events: none;
    pointer: default;
    border-color: grey;
}
.contact-i-header {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
}
input[type='text'] {
    width: 235;
}
#request-quote-container {
    height: 60px;
    width: 90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ADAEA9;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    background-color: #DADCD3;
}
h2 {
    opacity: .8;
    width: 284.917px;
    text-align: right;
}
.side-by-side {
    display: inline-block;
}
h5 {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
#item {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#triangle-up {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid black;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.slider {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 5s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}
.slider.closed {
    max-height: 0;
}
.slider2 {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration:.5s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
    max-height: 200px;
}
.slider2.closed {
    max-height: 0;
}
#submit_info {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.bottom_btns {
}
#sent_box {
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
#write_box {
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
#send_box {
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.cart_parts {
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#cart_top {
    height: 40px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    background-color: #DADCD3;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow:
}
#cart_body {
    text-align: center;
}
.close_button {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 90px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 11px;
    background-color: lightGrey;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.close_span {
    display: inline-block;
}
.close_button:hover {
    color: red;
    border: 2px solid red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#script_no {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#not_supported {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}
#ter {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: red;
}
#submit-box {
    margin: 45px auto;
}
#tbr {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id='cart_top' class='cart_parts'> <dt class='list-item' style='margin-top: 10px;'>
     View your Quote
    </dt>

    <dd class='list-item'>
        <div id='triangle-up' class='side-by-side' style='float: right; margin-right: 20px; cursor: pointer; margin-top: 15px;' onClick='hider2()'></div>
    </dd>
</div>
<div id='cart_body' class='cart_parts slider2 closed'></div>
```